# Nested trigger doesn't fire - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012, dml

I have three tables, `POI` (PoiId as int), `Relations` (PoiId as int, RouteId as int) and `Route` (RouteId as int). I have `AFTER INSERT` trigger on both `POI` and `Relations` trigger. `POI` trigger inserts values into `Relations` table, and `Relations` trigger updates `Route` table.

Problem is when I insert something in `POI`, first trigger fires and inserts row in `Relations`. **BUT**, second (on `Relations`) trigger doesn't fire at all. If I directly insert into `Relations`, then trigger on `Relations` fires as requested. What is going on?

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101.aspx? I believe that they are (by default) disabled.

Comment: @Ralph Thank you very much!